# How to hard code binary data to string

Tags: c++, c++11, binaryfiles

I want to test serialized data conversion in my application, currently the object is stored in file and read the binary file and reloading the object.

In my unit test case I want to test this operation. As the file operations are costly I want to hard code the binary file content in the code itself.

How can I do this?

Currently I am trying like this,

```
std::string FileContent = "\00\00\00\00\00.........";
```

and it is not working.

Comment: use with `x` prefix. e.g. `\x00\x00` etc

Comment: Or octal like `"\0\0\0"` etc.

Comment: Neither of the above two will make it to a string AFAIK.

Comment: Using std::string for binary data, beuhh... It would be simpler and cleaner to use a plain char array or if you don't like plain arrays a std::array or std::vector of characters. You would avoid stupid errors of stopping on first null when initializing from a const char *.

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector<uint8_t>` rather than a string?

Comment: Problem is I am testing the code that has already written, there they are used string, so I cant able to modify that code

Comment: @GilsonPJ doesn't sound convincing

Comment: @mash sorry I thought std::vector<uint8_t> using in the class, let me try in my code and I will post the result

Comment: I am getting compilation error when I tried std::vector<uint8_t> FileContent = {"\00\00\00\00\00........."};

Comment: @GilsonPJ: try this: `std::vector<uint8_t> FileContent = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, ... };`

Comment: @lorro its a very big file. is there any other option to convert the bin file to hexadecimal?

Comment: @Gilson PJ "I am getting compilation error when I tried std::vector<uint8_t> FileContent = {"\00\00\00\00\00........."};" - of course you are. You are trying to initialize the vector with a character literal. You need to put the data in as individual bytes `= {0x01, 0x02, 0x03}` etc.

Comment: @Gilson PJ "is there any other option to convert the bin file to hexadecimal?" - of course there is. Writing such a tool yourself is trivial, but if you just search a bit you'll find that *many* people have already written such tools that you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that a string can contain `'\0'`, but here you're still initializing it from `const char*`, which, by definition, stops at the first `'\0'`. I'd recommend you to use `uint8_t[]` or even `uint32_t[]` (that is, without passing to `std::string`), even if the second might have up to 3 bytes of overhead (but it's more compact when in source). That's e.g. how X bitmaps are usually stored.

Another possibility is base64 encoding, which is printable but needs (a relatively quick) decoding.

If you *really* want to put the `const char[]` to a `std::string`, first convert the pointer to `const char*`, then use the two-iterator constructor of `std::string`. While it's true that `std::string` can hold `'\0'`, it's somewhat an antipattern to store binary in a string, thus I'm not giving the exact code, just the hint.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you need, however probably not recommended as most people wouldn't expect an `std::string` to contain null bytes.

```
std::string FileContent { "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", 5 };
```